# Disable past dates and enable only certain future dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, mindate

I am attempting to use the `jQuery` datepicker, but wish to disable all past days and allow only future Thursdays. I can get it to allow Thursdays, but the `minDate` functionality I add doesn't work with it. This is my code:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#input_40_4').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 4, ""];}
   });
});

$(function () {
    $("#input_40_4'").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
});

</script>
```

Can someone explain why these don't work together?

Comment: have you tried putting them in the same initialization code? ie: `{beforeShowDay: ... , minDate: 0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more options to the `datepicker` by separating them by commas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_40_4').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 4, ""];},
        minDate : 0
        // you can add more options here as well, just seperate them by commas
   });
});
```

The reason why they didn't work in your question was because you would overwrite the options from the datepicker created in the function on line 10 with the options from the datepicker in the documentReady section.

You were basically saying create a new datepicker with mindate:0, never mind create a new one with only Tuesdays.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is you are overwriting the effects of the first datepicker call with the second one.

Put both of the options in one options object

```
$("#input_40_4'").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 4, ""];},
    minDate: 0
});
```

Demo

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 4, ""];},
    minDate: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"></link>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 3, ""];},
    minDate: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"></link>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your code. Explain your train of thought so we can better understand your answer. Thanks.